# Sum of all the different column values group by another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-visualization, qlikview

I have  a table like this:

```
project_name      janExp      febExp      marchExp      aprilExp
project A           1000      1100          1200          1300
project B           2000      2100          2200          2300
project C           3000      3100          3200          3300
project A           500       600            700           800
project B           100       200            300           400
```

I want output like this:

```
project_name          janExp      febExp      marchExp        aprilExp
Project A              1500        1700           1900           2100
Project B              2100        2300           2500           2700
project C              3000        3100           3200           3300
```

I am new to Qlikview,  can someone tell me what expression i need to write for it?

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a straight table[image]!

Your script should look like this:

[image]

You can see the expression in the title. Use the Field 'project_name' as a dimension:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
project_name,
Sum (janExp),
Sum (febExp),
Sum (marchExp)
From table
Group by project_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following script. Note that the `GROUP BY` and the `SUM()` are in the `LOAD` part. This is the set of expressions used by QlikView. You can also do this in two steps, by performing a resident load then a group by in SQL part.

```
Load 
  project_name, 
  sum(janExp) as janExp, 
  sum(febExp) as febExp, 
  sum(marchExp) as marchExp
Group By 
   project_name;
SQL 
  Select * From table;
```